# Interviewing order; the effects of going first in recruiter's evaluation

Tags: interviewing

This question might be seen as slightly opinion based for those who are unfamiliar with the area but I'm mostly interested in what (if any) *real evidence might exist*.

If given the opportunity to pick when you're being interviewed, is it a good idea to request to go in first?

Will I become the benchmark all the others are judged against or will there be a certain novelty factor about the first interviewee which once worn off might have a negative psychological impact in the minds of the interviewers?

Also, is it better to pick a time in the morning or afternoon to make the best impression?

Comment: You may be on the wrong site if you're looking for "real evidence" (the existing answer providing that notwithstanding).

Comment: "*is it a good idea to request to go in first*" - What makes you think you'll ever be able to? Who's to say they haven't interviewed people on other days? Who's to say they haven't already arranged interviews in earlier timeslots that you're no longer seeing? In my opinion, despite your disclaimers this question is of dubious value. Even if *decent* research existed on this, we're not an academic site, our Q&A should have practical, actionable value.

Comment: *real evidence* not so sure this exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, is it better to pick a time in the morning or afternoon to make
>   the best impression?

Based on my experience, it **is so subjective** as to whether or not to *go first or somewhere after* from the person/people interviewing you perspective it isn't even worth worrying about.  For instance, if you decide to go first, and the initial person you spoke with had a fight with their significant other, I would say your chances are less in terms of making a good impression because the person is most likely not in a good mood.  In other words, *in my experience*, a lot of this is out of your control.

What I **would** suggest, is you try to pick a time that is best **for you**.  Instead of worrying about what is the best time to interview with one or more people whom you never met, try to focus on when **you are at your best**.

As side note, you can never be penalized for dressing nice for an interview.  It shows that you care about making a solid first impression.  Also, read and then re-read your resume.  Typo's and grammatical errors on your resume can have a negative impact too.

Comment: Great answer but think about the last time you went car shopping, in your enthusiasm did the first car make an impression any different than the following cars you evaluated?  Or was it forgotten after having seen 4 other cars equally good?  Surely there has to be something definable..?

Answer (score 2):

> If given the opportunity to pick when you're being interviewed, is it a good idea to request to go in first?

According to [this article on Psychological Science](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0956797612459762) seems that it is indeed **better to go first**.

The reason why is because of the "narrow bracketing" phenomena, which is basically some form of bias towards the first candidate(s) in comparison with later candidates.

From the abstract, emphasis mine:

> We conjectured that in such situations [when +1 candidates are evaluated in a day], individuals engage in **narrow bracketing**, assessing each subset in isolation and then—for any given subset—avoiding much deviation from the expected overall distribution of judgments. For instance, **an interviewer who has already highly recommended three applicants on a given day may be reluctant to do the same for a fourth applicant**. Data from more than **9,000 M.B.A. interviews** supported this prediction.

Comment: Is there something in the article body that specifically supports the interpretation that "it is better to go first"? I don't think the abstract in itself supports that. It gives an example of one scenario where this effect would disadvantage the last candidate, but it seems just as likely to benefit the last one - if an interviewer has *not* yet given any "highly recommended" that day, they may be more willing to do so for the last candidate.

Comment: *an interviewer who has already highly recommended three applicants* -- if this is the case why are they still interviewing? Also, I would argue that the **fourth could even be better than the other three**.  The point it this piece is completely subjective.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent I won't quote all the article, but I suggest you read it if you have some time as it is quite interesting. OP asked for *facts* about some evidence that supports the hypothesis; a scientific paper is as factual as you can get, besides being non-subjective as other answers that one could provide (like saying if *I* think it's better or not). Seems that 9k interviews has some weight

Comment: @DarkCygnus having now read the full article - it's interesting, and definitely relevant to this question, but it definitely does *not* support your interpretation that "it is better to go first". In fact, Table 1 shows that the correlation between "number of interviews so far by same interviewer that day" and interview score is *not* significant even at p=0.1.

Answer (score 0):

> If given the opportunity to pick when you're being interviewed, is it
>   a good idea to request to go in first?

It's unlikely you would have your choice in that regard.

If you believe you are far stronger than most candidates, you should go first. You'll make a great impression that others won't be able to compete with.

If you believe you are about the same as all other candidates, you should go last. You'll make a final impression, that may be more lasting.

> Also, is it better to pick a time in the morning or afternoon to make
>   the best impression?

That depends mostly on you.

I'm a "morning person". I have my energy at its highest in the morning, so for me I would make my best impression then.

But others are afternoon people and project their best later in the day.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood something, this seems to be saying that having the stronger candidates go before the weak ones is better both for the strong candidates and for the weak ones, which doesn't seem possible assuming a fixed number of vacancies?